# Get all Parse objects with single API request

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

Is it possible to get all [Parse](http://parse.com) objects (of different classes) with a single API request, using the Parse iOS/Android SDK? How?

Comment: I'd like to know too, I haven't found any solution so far. I have 4 classes and use 4 API requests to get all my objects. Have you tried their forums ?

Comment: @rdurand https://parse.com/questions/get-all-parse-objects-with-single-api-request

Comment: Thanks ! Too bad it's not possible !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Parse Help [forum](https://www.parse.com/questions/get-all-parse-objects-with-single-api-request#answer-at-the-moment-it-is-not-possible-to-do-this):

> At the moment, it is not possible to do this with a single API request.

Answer (score 0):

Include latest library i.e. Parse-1.3.1.jar and then go to the queries section of android and ios

https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries